# What expression to use when a wave hits the beach and fades away?

Tags: expressions

I am looking for word or expression that refers to the moment when a wave, with all its strength, closes itself, hits the beach and fades away.

[image: Wave on the beach]

Comment: It "breaks" on the beach and then "ebbs" away.

Answer (score 21):

After the wave breaks, it is called ***swash***.

> Swash, in geography, is known as a turbulent layer of water that washes up on the beach after an incoming wave has broken. Swash consists of two phases: **uprush** (onshore flow) and **backwash** (offshore flow). [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swash)

[image]
<sub>*Image source: geographyas.info*</sub>

Comment: The only thing I'll add to this diagram is that the crest rises *because* the friction is slowing down the *lower levels* of the wave, so the top is moving *faster*. This is why waves can break even at a distance from the shore, if the gradient of the ground underneath is right.

Answer (score 13):

You could say the wave is *ebbing*. Typically, *ebb* is used to describe the tide going out, but it could also be applied to a single wave receding toward the sea.

**ebb** - flow back or recede

Answer (score 9):

I think the term is that the wave is "breaking" from [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/break):

> 5.5(Of waves) curl over and dissolve into foam: the Caribbean sea was breaking gently on the shore

I think it can also be considered to be "[crashing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crash)" onto the shore which is similar but seems to have a more strong or violent image.

Comment: Waves can 'break' anywhere,,, I like 'crash' for when they hit the shoreline.

Comment: Indeed, *break* has nothing to do with shoreline, but *crash* is the first thought that came to my mind.

Comment: Possibly also "breaking" can be used when it's curling over and dissolving as described in the definition and once they've hit the shore and are no longer waves, the waves have already "broken" but yes, it's not perfect which is probably why "gently" and "on the shore" is included in the example to provide the rest of the context such as strength of break and where. I like "swash" suggested by the user above.

Answer (score 5):

I'd still describe it as a wave (as it seems you want to still acknowledge it as such), so I'd call it a `receding wave`.

Answer (score 4):

Big waves *pound on* the shore, small waves *lap at* the shore. They *roll* and *crash* into the shore. They *wash over* sand and rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Living at the beach most of my life, we simply say in common language, "I love the sound of the waves crashing on the beach."

Author George L. Babec

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for ornate language, the options below would work for me. Obviously, they convey slightly different meanings.

"caressingly assaulted"

"assaultively caressed"

Ex: The waves caressingly assaulted the long arc of the Pacific beach.

Ex: Long waves assaultively caressed the dry skeleton of the abandoned schooner.

Comment: Either of these verbs is fine on its own, slapping an adverbial form of one onto the other is a bit excessive. That is, large violent waves can be said to *assault* and soothing calm waves can be said to *caress*.

Comment: I may be in the minority but I find ornate language excessive and indulgent. Readers deserve concise writing, and you can be concise without sacrificing detail.